# What is the simplest way to animate an object fresh out of 3d view?

Tags: animation

There's an animation button besides render in the right hand side bar but how do I use it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? it is not clear what you are asking, please edit your question and provide more details about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Even if this wasn't a joke, this question is rather funny. But for clarity: The **Animation** button does the same as the render button but for several frames consecutively.

Comment: No,no that button is part of the render controls. You click that to render your animation, not animate something.

Comment: The wave modifier isn't animation? Like you apply it then render. And yes, this isn't a joke.